# Cost of cloning iterator originating from into_iter() in Rust?

Tags: rust, iterator, clone

I'm trying to figure out what is the cost of cloning iterators that originate from `into_iter()` in Rust, but can't find anything meaningful.

Consider the code like this:

```
let v = vec![1,2,3,4,...]; // Some large vector
let iter = v.into_iter().map(...some closure...);
let another_iter = iter.clone(); // What is copied here??
```

Since I've moved the vector into an iterator, `iter` now owns the internal buffer with vector values. This is exactly what I want to achieve to abstract the container type.

However, what happens when I call `iter.clone()`? Does it copy the whole internal buffer with data (could be very expensive) or just copy the iterator state while referring to the same buffer (cheap)?

Is there an idiomatic way of storing and cheaply cloning such iterators originating from `into_iter()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As each [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) implementation can define it's own `type IntoIter: Iterator<Item = Self::Item>;` the answer is it totally depends on the iterator produced by `into_iter`.

For `std::vec::IntoIter` it is cloning the internal buffer as can be seen by the [`Clone` implementation of it](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec/into_iter.rs.html#386-395):

> ```rust
> impl<T: Clone, A: Allocator + Clone> Clone for IntoIter<T, A> {
>     #[cfg(not(test))]
>     fn clone(&self) -> Self {
>         self.as_slice().to_vec_in(self.alloc.deref().clone()).into_iter()
>     }
>     #[cfg(test)]
>     fn clone(&self) -> Self {
>         crate::slice::to_vec(self.as_slice(), self.alloc.deref().clone()).into_iter()
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies the things! However, I wonder what is the rationale of such design? Since this is immutable iterator, what prevents several copies of sharing the same buffer?

Comment: @yesint `vec.into_iter()` _moves_ items out of the vec, which prevents access from where they were stored originally. If you want to have multiple iterators share the same storage, use `vec.iter()`, which returns references instead.

Comment: @yesint there is nothing immutable about `vec::IntoIter` it *owns* the items meaning it can do anything it likes with them. Also to get items from it has to be mutable and it will return owned items as well. Remember you can always `let mut x = x;` to be able to mutate owned items even if the original binding is immutable.

Answer (score 4):

It clones the entire buffer. Essentially equal to `vec.clone()`, except that it discards already-iterated items. [You can see the code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.73.0/src/alloc/vec/into_iter.rs.html#389).

You can use [`Itertools::tee()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tee) instead, but it will be more efficient only if the `Vec` is very big and you keep both iterators around the same item, so there isn't a big lag. Even its docs warn:

> **Note:** If the iterator is clonable, prefer using that instead of using this method. Cloning is likely to be more efficient.